# Merging two halves of a singly linked list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

In a written test I came across a question which reads as follows:

We are given an integer linked list of which both first half and second half are sorted independently. Write a function to merge the two parts to create one single sorted linked list.

**Constraint: do not use any extra space.**

Test Cases and output:
 **Input List1 :**
4->5->6->7->1->2->3; 
 **Output :**
 1->2->3->4->5->6->7 
**Input 2:** 
 5->6->7->8->1->2->3->4; 
 **Output 2 :**
 1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8

What I can think of is by using two pointers: one for the first half traversal and one for the second half traversal. Using them I can traverse from head to middle (using 1st pointer) and from middle to last (using 2nd Pointer). While traversing both parts simultaneously, I can compare values and swap when needed. 
But this solution employs use of two pointers which consumes memory.

Can it be done without using any memory? 
As it was a written test, I cannot ask for clarifications. 
Assistance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "Do not use extra space" sounds like you're not allowed to allocate extra memory for the sorting, not like the use of pointers or intermediate variables being forbidden. Frankly, I find it quite difficult to comprehend how you could even perform this sort without pointers.

Comment: It seems likely that question really means, "use only O(log *n*) extra memory": i.e. give a LOGSPACE algorithm.

Comment: @ Esa Lakaniemi: So was I correct in the direction I was thinking?

Comment: @ Gareth Rees: I could not comprehend what actually you want to imply..With the given problem statement, two pointers is what we need (and actually a third one while swapping). So that is fixed. It does not depend on the size of the linked list (as in case of O(logn) ).

Comment: In order to be able to point to an element in a list of size *n*, a pointer must have size log *n*. For example, if a list has 65536 elements, you need a pointer at least 16 bits wide in order to point to an element of that list.

Comment: even in the strict sense of "not using extra memory", you can do it, as the 2 or 3 pointers required surely fit on the processor registers :-)

Comment: @salva: Ah!! my bad..that I did not attempt the question thinking my approach to be wrong. Thanks for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When they say "do not use extra space", they do not mean pointers and scalars; they do mean "arrays" and "dynamically allocated structures". In your case, the amount of memory is fixed.

Merging two ordered lists is simple: first, cut the list in half, and then re-arrange `next` pointers of its elements to make the list sorted.

You will need three pointers - `newHead`, `head1`, and `head2`.

- Initialize `head1` and `head2` to the `head` of the original list
- Advance `head2` until you see a break in the sorted sequence (i.e. when `head2->next->value` is less than `head2->value`). Cut the list there by setting `head2->next` to `NULL`; keep the original `head2->next` - it is your new `head2`

At this point, you have two independently ordered, separate linked lists, and you can apply the classic merge algorithm. Set `newHead` to the smaller element of `head1` or `head2`, and then move in a loop, setting the `next` pointer of the current last element to the smaller of `head1` or `head2`. Once you hit `head1->next == NULL` or `head2->next == NULL`, assign the head of the other list to the `next` of the list that ran out of elements first. You are done - `newHead` now points to the beginning of a sorted list.